# Remove et al listing in bibliography; list all authors by full name

Tags: biblatex, author-number

I'm currently using TexMaker and Biber on a Ubuntu machine.
I'm quite happy with just using the standard numeric citation style, safe for 1 thing: it shortens all authors in my bibliography to "First author et al". I was wondering how to set it to list all authors with their full name? The answer is probably pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to find it.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}

\newpage

\printbibliography
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the loading option: `maxcitenames=50`, say (if you have no more than 50 authors in your bibliography). If you want this specification to be valid also for the bibliography, simply use `maxnames=50`.

For fullnames, `firstinits=false`.

Comment: As I understood it when you use maxcitenames=50 a bibliography entry with 50 authors will list all 50 authors but if that entry has 51 authors it gets shortened with et. al.? Did I get that wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's also a `min(cite)names` key that sets the number of authors that are printed before `et al.` The default is `1`.

Comment: OK, just because I understood your answer more in the sense 'if you have more 50 authors in your bibliography (as a whole)' and not per entry in the bibliography. But that might be because my English sometimes sucks :)

Comment: I'm not always very explicit, I must confess. I tend to think my interlocutors will complete my words… :o)

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked! One simple addition to the preamble, and all is fixed :)