# List all co-authors

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm listing all my publications using biblatex (for my resume), using a separate bib file (lastname.bib). I'm using biblatex with biber backend.

I would add a section to list all my co-authors. Is there any way of doing this automatically?

Comment: Do you just want `maxbibnames=999`? See also [biblatex: displaying all authors of multi-author works in the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1554/35864), [Remove et al listing in bibliography; list all authors by full name](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246461/35864).

Comment: No, thanks for the suggestion. But, that is per reference, I'm looking for something across all references.

Comment: Mhhh, I'm not sure I really understand what you want, but the above is not per reference, it displays all names for all references. I do have the feeling though that you are not really after this option after reading your comments below PLK's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found an answer, using an author index. I've tried to include a MWE below, but I might have added a few lines which are unnecessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[indexing=true,maxnames=99,style=authoryear,datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[program=makeindex,options=-s mystyle.ist,title=List of Co-Authors]
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

% Declare the coauthor name field
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name]{coauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{coauthor}
\end{filecontents}

% Required to remove the page number after the author in the index
\makeatletter
\let\mygobble\@gobble
\LetLtxMacro\OldIndex\index
\renewcommand{\index}[1]{\OldIndex{#1|mygobble}} 
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
quote '+'
delim_0 " "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
delim_n " "
\end{filecontents*}

% I use a slightly more general bib, with a single author publication, and co-authors over several papers.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{test1,
 AUTHOR = {Arthur Smith and James Jones and Bill Smiley and Jake Wrath},
 JOURNALTITLE = {A Journal},
 YEAR   = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{test2,
 AUTHOR = {Philippa Smyth and Arthur Smith and Bill Likely},
 JOURNALTITLE = {Another Journal},
 YEAR   = {2011}
}

@ARTICLE{test3,
 AUTHOR = {Arthur Smith},
 JOURNALTITLE = {The Best Journal},
 YEAR   = {2013}
}

@ARTICLE{test4,
 AUTHOR = {Philippa Smyth and Arthur Smith and James Jones},
 JOURNALTITLE = {Again Another Journal},
 YEAR   = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Create a "coauthor" name list which is a copy of the "author" name
% list, minus oneself (assuming you are "Arthur Smith" and this is how
% your name always appears in the .bib - you can always make more
% sophisticated regexps if there is name variation)
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=author,
             match=\regexp{Arthur\s+Smith}, final]
       \step[fieldsource=author, fieldset=coauthor, origfieldval]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthor,
             match=\regexp{Arthur\s+Smith\s+and\s+},
             replace={}]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthor,
             match=\regexp{\s+and\s+Arthur\s+Smith},
             replace={}]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthor,
             match=\regexp{Arthur\s+Smith},
             replace={}]             
    }
  }
}

% Sort the biblist by coauthor name
\DeclareSortingScheme{coauthor}{\sort{\field{coauthor}}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{\ifbibindex{\indexnames{coauthor}}{}}


% Driver to print the biblist items
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{coauthor}{\printnames{coauthor}}

% Simple bibenvironment to print the biblist
\defbibenvironment{coauthor}{\list{}{}}{\endlist}{\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\raggedright
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Since you're using Biblatex, you could make everything a bit easier by using string to store, at least, the name of the author (`Arthur Smith` in your example), cf. [this documentation](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/).

Answer (score 9):

Using the latest `biblatex` 3.3 and `biber` 2.4 development versions from Sourceforge. New mapping functionality allows loops and creating new entries and so it is possible to split up name fields into dedicated entrytypes for correct printing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% Declare the coauthor name field
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list, datatype=name, label=true]{coauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{coauthor}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[coauthor]{coauthor}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{test1,
 AUTHOR = {Arthur Smith and James Jones and Bill Smiley and Jake Wrath},
 JOURNALTITLE = {A Journal},
 YEAR   = {2010}
}

@ARTICLE{test2,
 AUTHOR = {Philippa Smyth and Arthur Smith and Bill Likely},
 JOURNALTITLE = {Another Journal},
 YEAR   = {2011}
}

@ARTICLE{test3,
 AUTHOR = {Arthur Smith},
 JOURNALTITLE = {The Best Journal},
 YEAR   = {2013}
}

@ARTICLE{test4,
 AUTHOR = {Philippa Smyth and Arthur Smith and James Jones},
 JOURNALTITLE = {Again Another Journal},
 YEAR   = {2014}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% 1. First, check if the author list contain me, here, "Arthur Smith"
% 2. Copy the author field to a temporary field "coauthortext". We don't need
%    datamodel declarations for this as this will be deleted after use and
%    will never get anywhere near code that queries the data model.
% 3. Remove me (Arthur Smith) from this temporary copy of the author list
% 4. Turn the resulting field into a comma-separated list
% 5. Loop over this comma-separated list, creating new entries of type
%    "coauthor" each with a "coauthor" name list field containing the data
%    from the loop variable
% 6. Remove the temporary author field copy "coauthortext"
%
% The special $MAPLOOP variable holds each value of the csv field name by
% the "foreach" option on the \map macro.
% The special $MAPUNIQ variable is a random string generated automatically
% at the beginning of each \map section. This can be when you need a unique
% string as here because entrykeys should be new unique.
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=author,
             match=\regexp{Arthur\s+Smith}, final]
       \step[fieldsource=author,
             notmatch=\regexp{^Arthur\s+Smith$}, final]
       \step[fieldsource=author, fieldset=coauthortext, origfieldval]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthortext,
             match=\regexp{Arthur\s+Smith\s+and\s+},
             replace={}]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthortext,
             match=\regexp{\s+and\s+Arthur\s+Smith},
             replace={}]
       \step[fieldsource=coauthortext,
             match=\regexp{\s+and\s+},
             replace={,}]
    }
    \map[overwrite, foreach=coauthortext]{
      \step[fieldsource=coauthortext, match=\regexp{.}, final]
      \step[entrynew=\regexp{$MAPUNIQ}, entrynewtype=coauthor]
      \step[entrytarget=\regexp{$MAPUNIQVAL}, fieldset=coauthor, fieldvalue=\regexp{$MAPLOOP}]
      \step[entrytarget=\regexp{$MAPUNIQVAL}, fieldset=options, fieldvalue=skipbib]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=coauthortext, null]
    }
  }
}

% Sort the biblist by coauthor name
\DeclareSortingScheme{coauthor}{
  \sort{
        \field{coauthor}
  }
}

% Driver to print the biblist items
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{coauthor}{%
  \printnames{coauthor}}

% bibcheck to strip duplicates
\defbibcheck{coauthor}{%
  \ifcsdef{\strname{coauthor}}
    {\skipentry}
    {\savenamecs{coauthor}{\strname{coauthor}}}}

% Simple bibenvironment to print the biblist
\defbibenvironment{coauthor}
{\list{}
  {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
   \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
   \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
   \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
% This will automatically use the "coauthor" sorting scheme/biblist/driver etc.
\printbiblist[title=CoAuthors]{coauthor}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed a start (I had to update my latex package to get the example running, but now it works). I would like to get a single list of all co-authors alphabetically. I'm going to scan the docs if I can find something.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt that this is possible with the current functionality. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: See edits - this is now easier due to new mapping functionality.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll have a look tomorrow. I was trying my self now a solution with author indexing (and then removing the index). Seems to be a reasonable alternative, I'll post tomorrow.

Comment: Your example is nicer than my answer below (since that one depends on making an index), but with your example, I run into problems when adding a single author paper, or the same co-author on different paper, see test3 and test4 reference in my example.

Comment: See edits for fixes for these two issues. You will need to get biblatex 3.3 again (but not biber 2.4 again) as there is a need for a new internal macro. To get rid of duplicates, you use a bibcheck which is automatically used by the biblist.